# How to implement progress Indicator in web view for every page load flutter?

Tags: android, flutter, sdk

I am currently showing progress indicator before webview load using this code:

My Full main.dart code:

```
import 'dart:io';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:webview_flutter/webview_flutter.dart';
//import 'package:mtcl/utils/AppColors.dart';
import 'package:custom_splash/custom_splash.dart';
import 'package:connectivity/connectivity.dart';

void main() {
  //runApp(MyApp());

  //var result = Connectivity().checkConnectivity();

  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  runApp(MyApp());

  // if (result == ConnectivityResult.none) {
  //   WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  //   runApp(MyApp());
  // } else if (result == ConnectivityResult.mobile) {
  //   WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  //   runApp(MyApp());
  // } else if (result == ConnectivityResult.wifi) {
  //   WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  //   runApp(MyApp());
  // }
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
        title: "MTCL Client",
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
        theme: ThemeData(
          primarySwatch: Colors.red,
        ),
        home: Scaffold(body: splash()));
  }
}

class splash extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _splashState createState() => _splashState();
}

class _splashState extends State<splash> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return CustomSplash(
      backGroundColor: Color(0xFFFF9800),
      imagePath: "assets/images/logo.png",
      home: WebViewClass(),
      duration: 10,
      animationEffect: "zoom-in",
    );
  }
}

class WebViewClass extends StatefulWidget {
  WebViewState createState() => WebViewState();
}

class WebViewState extends State<WebViewClass> {
  num position = 1;

  final key = UniqueKey();

  doneLoading(String A) {
    setState(() {
      position = 0;
    });
  }

  startLoading(String A) {
    setState(() {
      position = 1;
    });
  }

  //Check Internet Code Starts

  //Check Internet Code Ended here
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        //appBar: AppBar(title: Text('Show ProgressBar While Loading Webview')),
        appBar: PreferredSize(
          child: Container(),
          preferredSize: Size.fromHeight(0.0),
        ),
        body: IndexedStack(index: position, children: <Widget>[
          WebView(
            initialUrl: 'http://110.38.4.4/login/client',
            javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,
            key: key,
            onPageFinished: doneLoading,
            onPageStarted: startLoading,
          ),
          Container(
            color: Colors.white,
            child: Center(
                child: CircularProgressIndicator(
              valueColor: new AlwaysStoppedAnimation<Color>(Colors.red),
            )),
          ),
        ]));
  }
}
```

Now what I need is to show the progress indicator instantly for every action like If the user clicks on login button after filling login credential, I want the progress indicator to be shown instantly after clicking the button while now the progress indicator is showing after a few moments of button click. How can I achieve such thing in flutter?

Comment: did you get a solution for this?

Answer (score 2):

You can add your code that triggers the progress indicator inside `navigationDelegate`:

```
WebView(
  initialUrl: 'https://flutter.dev',
  navigationDelegate: (NavigationRequest request) {
    print('Navigating to ${request.url}');
    // Call any code here that you want
    return NavigationDecision.navigate;
  },
),
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on navigationDelegate as suggested by Soares , this is my full working code

```
class _WikipediaExplorerState extends State<WikipediaExplorer> {
  Completer<WebViewController> _controller = Completer<WebViewController>();
  final Set<String> _favorites = Set<String>();

  String title, url;
  bool isLoading = true;
  final _key = UniqueKey();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Facebook Test Webview'),
        // This drop down menu demonstrates that Flutter widgets can be shown over the web view.
        actions: <Widget>[
          NavigationControls(_controller.future),
          Menu(_controller.future, () => _favorites),
        ],
      ),
      body: Builder(builder: (BuildContext context) {
        return Stack(
          children: <Widget>[
            WebView(
              initialUrl: 'https://www.facebook.com/',
              javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,
              onWebViewCreated: (WebViewController webViewController) {
                _controller.complete(webViewController);
              },
              // TODO(iskakaushik): Remove this when collection literals makes it to stable.
              // ignore: prefer_collection_literals
              javascriptChannels: <JavascriptChannel>[
                _toasterJavascriptChannel(context),
              ].toSet(),
              navigationDelegate: (NavigationRequest request) {
                if (request.url.startsWith('https://www.youtube.com/')) {
                  print('blocking navigation to $request}');
                  return NavigationDecision.prevent;
                }
                print('allowing navigation to $request');
                setState(() {
                  isLoading = true;
                });
                return NavigationDecision.navigate;
              },
              onPageFinished: (String url) {
                print('Page finished loading: $url');
                setState(() {
                  isLoading = false;
                });
              },
            ),
            isLoading
                ? Center(
                    child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                  )
                : Stack(),
          ],
        );
      }),
    );

  }
}
```

Every time a new link is clicked within the app, a circular progress dialog will be initiated